# Angular [object Object] result instead of data

Tags: json, angular

I've been trying to display the json result i'm getting from my backend. However I'm not able to display this json fully in my angular front-end. The json I'm getting also has . and - in it's naming. These are my classes currently and i can display the name and title but the data returns [object Object]
How can i return the data object and use this for instead in a form?
Unfortunately I don't have the possibility to format the json in the back-end
Models

```
  export interface Data {
    "Cloud-Features:CloudFeatures": CloudFeatures
  }
  
  export interface CloudFeatures {
    "redis.hosts": string
    "sentinel.active": boolean
    "script.type": ScriptType[]
  }
  
  export interface ScriptType {
    name: string
    features: string[]
  }
  export interface Root {
    name: string
    title: string
    data: Data
  }
```

Component

```
export class CloudFeaturesComponent implements OnInit {

  cloudfeatures!: any; 
  constructor(private cloudfeatureservice : CloudFeaturesService, private titleService: Title) { 
    this.titleService.setTitle("Cloud Features")
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadCloudFeaturesConfig();
  }

  loadCloudFeaturesConfig() {
    this.cloudfeatureservice.getCloudConfig().subscribe(cloudfeatures => {
      this.cloudfeatures = cloudfeatures
    })
  }
}
```

Maybe it's also better to use Root instead of any here?
Service

```
export class CloudFeaturesService {

  baseUrl = environment.ApiUrl;

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { 
  }

  getCloudConfig(){
    return this.http.get<any>(this.baseUrl + 'cloudfeatures');
  }

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="tile sm-12">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="box">
        <h1></h1>

        <p>{{ cloudfeatures | json }}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        {{ cloudfeatures.name }}
      </div>
      <div>
        {{ cloudfeatures.title }}
      </div>
      <div>
        {{ cloudfeatures.data }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSON

```
{
    "name":"CloudFeatures",
    "title":"CloudFeatures model",
    "data":{
        "Cloud-Features:CloudFeatures":{
            "redis.hosts":"TestURL2",
            "sentinel.active":true,
            "script.type":[
                {
                    "name":"test123",
                    "features":[
                        "Start",
                        "test123",
                        "qwerty"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: .data is an object. You have to read its properties using the dot notation

Comment: Yes but if I for example use cloudfeatures.data.Cloud-Features:CloudFeatures.redis.hosts I get a lot of errors like "Parser Error: Unexpected token ':'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your problem is that `{{cloudfeatures.data}}` only renders `[object Object]`. This happens, because 'cloudfeatures.data' is no primitive type, but an JSON object. If you want to render the whole JSON object, you should use the `json` pipe.

If you want to access a specific property of this object, you can use either dot notation **or** bracket notation. Bracket notation is needed in your case, since you have special characters in your object keys. Example:

```
{{ cloudfeatures.data["Cloud-Features:CloudFeatures"] }}
```

Comment: Thanks didn't know about this bracket notation! Already found the json pipe option but wanted to use these parameters in some sort of form to update them!

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer did help you, please remember to accept it and close your question if possible.

Answer (score 0):

use json pipe for data

example

```html
<div>
        {{ cloudfeatures.data | json }}
</div>
```